# Adding a new service to Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've added a new Service to an existing Angular project with:

```
$ ng generate service utils/new
```

Now I tried to move some methods from `AppService` to `NewService`.

Both services have the same constructor:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
```

And

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NewService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

Now in a `Component` I try to use `NewService` instead of `AppService` (I simply replace `AppService` with `NewService`).

```
@Component({
//...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private newService: NewService) {
    newService.doSomething(...);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
```

It compiles. But I get a runtime error: `ERROR TypeError: n.appService is undefined`

I could not understand what the debugger was saying so I made a guess: I added `private appService: AppService` to the constructor, although it is not being used at all in the code of `MyComponent`. So now I have this:

```
@Component({
//...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private appService: AppService, private newService: NewService) {
    newService.doSomething(...);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
```

Now it compiles, and I also don't get any runtime error.

This looks strange and counterintuitive to me. What did I miss here?

Do I need some configuration setting to declare the existence of `NewService`?

Comment: Well, that's weird, can you replicate it?

Comment: I can try. Should Service classes be declared in module files? I've read in another answer that they don't have to if I use `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`

Comment: If your service has the `providedIn: 'root'` parameter in the decorator you don't have to provide it to a module. When you will first use it in your class (in the constructor) the service will be created and the instance will be singleton.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: Taking this info into account, if I never try in my code to initialize a reference to `AppService` - is it possible to have a reference to `AppService` as `undefined`  in runtime?

Comment: I have never tried to create a service that I will not use to be honest :) But I tried that on stack-blitz and it seems to work fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kgehzf?file=src/app/app.service.ts

Comment: I don't see any new Service class in the link. Or trying to use the new Service in a Component constructor.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kgehzf?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

This happened because in the `html` view of `MyComponent` was a reference to an `AppService` method. Strangely, the project still compiled and only failed at runtime.

Usually when I refer in `html` views to entities that are not recognized, I get a compilation error.